# Sound output unpredictable

Tags: audio, bluetooth, kodi, vlc

I'm a bit at a loss to describe the issues I have because they don't really seem consistent to me. I use a raspberry pi 4 running raspbian.

- When I boot I have sound through 3,5 jack
- I can change sound to a bluetooth receiver
- If I change it back weirdness starts
  ** if on vlc, I can hear no output from mp3, if I restart vlc output is back
  ** if on chromium, I can only get sound back after a reboot

Bonus:

- in Kodi I can have sound from movies (flv, mp4), but never from mp3

Stuff I tried

- I have tried purging pulse audio because someone healed their issues through that
- I have reinstalled pulse audio
- I have installed pavucontrol
- I have installed blueman
- I have tried all audio outputs vlc gives me
- when I access raspi via kodi clients from UPnP Radio or another Linux machine, audio is fine

System

- Raspbian 10 buster; Kernel: Linux 5.4.72-v71+
- Kodi from Debian 17.6
- I have used this https://blog.vpetkov.net/2020/03/30/raspberry-pi-netflix-one-line-easy-install-along-with-hulu-amazon-prime-disney-plus-hbo-spotify-pandora-and-many-others/ to get netflix and prime running